# Deploy Calendar Tab visibility with sfdx

Tags: salesforcedx, tab

I am trying to retrieve metadata of custom Tab from a profile with SFDX
[image]

It should be logically something like that in metadata:

```
<tabVisibilities>
    <tab>standard-Calendar</tab>
    <visibility>DefaultOn</visibility>
</tabVisibilities>
```

but cant retrieve anything using `sfdx sfpowerkit:source:profile:retrieve -n "myProfile"`
or `sfdx force:source:push`

Is there a way to retrieve visibility on this tab for a specific profile ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, you'd need to pull the object as well as Profile to get the [ProfileTabVisibility](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm#:%7E:text=or%20not%20(false).-,ProfileTabVisibility,-ProfileTabVisibility%20represents%20the)

> ProfileTabVisibility represents the visibility of tabs for this profile. For version 17.0 and later, ProfileTabVisibility supports visibility of tabs for standard objects. **The manifest file must include the standard object corresponding to a standard tab to retrieve the tab visibility in a profile**.

However, you've hit an unsupported object. If you try to include Calendar - you'll get the following error:

> Can't retrieve non-customizable CustomObject named: Calendar

You'll see that Calendar is noted as [unsupported by the Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_unsupported_types.htm). As such, you'll have no way to do this except by manually editing the profile.

> The following components can’t be retrieved or deployed with Metadata API, and changes to them must be made manually in each of your organizations:
>
> Calendars